# Appending elements in lists in conversion to JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm coding a tool that reads a xlxs file and converts it to JSON. I'm using python 3 and 0.23.0 version of pandas for it. **Here is the data that my code is reading from xlxs:**

```
id     label        id_customer     label_customer    part_number 

6     Sao Paulo      CUST-99992         Brazil          7897

6     Sao Paulo      CUST-99992         Brazil          1437

92    Hong Hong      CUST-88888         China           785
```

==================================

**Here is my code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import json

file_imported = pd.read_excel('testing.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Plan1')

list_final  = []
for index, row in file_imported.iterrows():
    list1 = []
    list_final.append ({
        "id"       : int(row['id']),
        "label"    : str(row['label']),
        "Customer" : list1
        })

    list2 = []
    list1.append ({
       "id"       : str(row['id_customer']) ,
       "label"    : str(row['label_customer']),
       "number"   :  list2
       })

    list2.append({
        "part"    : str(row['part_number'])  
       })      

print (list_final)

with open ('testing.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(list_final, f, indent= True)
```

==================================

**My code is working, and this is the output that I'm getting:**

```
[
 {
  "id": 6,
  "label": "Sao Paulo",
  "Customer": [
   {
    "id": "CUST-99992",
    "label": "Brazil",
    "number" : [
    {
    "part": "7897"
    }
    ]
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "id": 6,
  "label": "Sao Paulo",
  "Customer": [
   {
    "id": "CUST-99992",
    "label": "Brazil",
    "number" : [
    {
    "part": "1437"
    }
    ]
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "id": 92,
  "label": "Hong Hong",
  "Customer": [
   {
    "id": "CUST-88888",
    "label": "China",
    "number" : [
    {
    "part": "785"
    }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

==================================

**and I need something like this:**

```
[
 {
  "id": 6,
  "label": "Sao Paulo",
  "Customer": [
   {
    "id": "CUST-99992",
    "label": "Brazil",
    "number" : [
    {
    "part": "7897"
    },
    {
    "part": "1437"
    }
    ]
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "id": 92,
  "label": "Hong Hong",
  "Customer": [
   {
    "id": "CUST-88888",
    "label": "China",
    "number" : [
    {
    "part": "785"
    }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

==================================

I have been searching for other topics here or any useful material, but haven't found yet. This is just a piece of my code and excel file (they are too big to post here). I believe I have to use 'if' statement to verify the content inside each row before add it in my json, but idk how to do it.

I can have a lot of 'Customer' and 'number' lists inside 'list_final' with different contents (this is why I created my excel like that)

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. I started based that your data is a pandas data frame.

```
def part(value):
    data = value.split("#")
    part_list = []
    for elements in data:
        part_list.append({"part" : elements})
    return part_list


path = yourpath
data = pd.read_excel(path)
data["part_number"] = data["part_number"].apply(lambda x: str(x))
data = data.groupby(["id", "label", "id_customer", "label_customer"], as_index=False).agg("#".join)
data["part_number"] = data["part_number"].apply(lambda x: part(x))
data = data.rename(columns={"id_customer": "Customer", "part_number": "number"})
data["label_customer"] = data["label_customer"].apply(lambda x: {"label": x})
data["Customer"] = data["Customer"].apply(lambda x: {"id": x})
data["number"] = data["number"].apply(lambda x: {"number": x})
data["Customer"] = data.apply(lambda x: [{**x["Customer"], **x["label_customer"], **x["number"]}], axis=1)
data = data[["id", "label", "Customer"]]
data.to_json(path_you_want, orient="records")
```

Comment: It works, but "Customer" is a list and must be initiate with '[' and not "{".

Comment: change this line:
    `data["Customer"] = data.apply(lambda x: {**x["Customer"], **x["label_customer"], **x["number"]}, axis=1)`
to:
    `data.apply(lambda x: [{**x["Customer"], **x["label_customer"], **x["number"]}], axis=1)`